# Mail without password in python

Tags: python, smtp, smtplib

I want to send mail to multiple ids using python. I am using smtplib to send it. I don't want to give my password in the script. But

> smtp.login(username,password)

fails if I do not. Is there any other library to do so.

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: you can find the solution [here](https://rajivpandit.wordpress.com/2013/09/19/how-to-send-email-by-python/).

Comment: Put the password in a file and restrict access to that file using your OS' commands. Reading that file in python provides the password.

Comment: You don't need to include your password in the script. You can set it as an  environmental variable and get it that way.

Comment: @Chamath how is that the solution? That link has the password defined in the file which  what the OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: @JHarris read it first. It has two methods for with and without authentication.

Comment: @Chamath clearly he needs to login if he's asking the question?

Comment: @maggs was your issue resolved?

Comment: @JHaris. Not yet. Though your solution helps somewhat but it again means i have to store my password somewhere. I have to set a cron job that directly mails the result to some people from my email id.

Comment: @maggs what solution are you hoping for? Either is has to prompt you, or you have to store it 'somewhere'? Can you elaborate on your use case / what you actually want to happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where / how to store credentials is a broad / big question. One way I like is to use an environment variable like this:

```
# In shell (to set the variable):
$ export MY_SMTP_PASS="this is a secret password"

# In python, to access it:
import os
smtp.login(username,os.environ['MY_SMTP_PASS'])
```

Obviously there are a bunch of other things you might want to do, check if it's set before using (raise an exception), etc...